# Using ActiveMQ to handle errors during webservice call

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a Java process which is listening for messages from a queue hosted by ActiveMQ and calls webservices if received status is `COMPLETE`.

I was also thinking of handling webservices calls using ActiveMQ as well. Is there a way I could make best use of ActiveMQ using maybe another queue?

This might help me in handling a scenario if one or more webservice calls fails in first attempt. But I'm trying to think what could I do to achieve something like this.

Do I need to forward webservice parameters to ActiveMQ queue and then look for something?

```java
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

// Working Code with JMS 2.0
@JmsListener(destination = "MessageProducer")
public void processBrokerQueues(String message) throws DaoException {
    ... 
    if(receivedStatus.equals("COMPLETE")) {

        // Do something inside COMPLETE                  
        // Need to call 8-10 webservices (shown only 2 below for breviety)

        ProcessBroker obj = new ProcessBroker();
        ProcessBroker obj1 = new ProcessBroker();

        // Calling webservice 1
        try {
            System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http POST request #1 ");
            obj.sendHTTPPOST1();
        } finally {
            obj.close();            
        }

        // Calling webservice 2.
        try {
            System.out.println("Testing 2 - Send Http POST request #2");
            obj1.sendHTTPPOST2();
        } finally {
            obj1.close();
        }                         
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**What I'm looking for:**

Basically If there is a possibility of creating an additional message queue, submit 8 messages to the queue, one corresponding to each webservice end point and have a queue listener dedicated to the message queue. If the message could not be delivered successfully, it could be put back on the queue for later delivery.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I am wondering if a webservice call fails (not using activemq) then is there a way I could handle such things by using another queue.

Comment: Yes, I would like to retry the message later. Basically If there is a possibility of creating an additional message queue, submit 8 messages to the queue, one corresponding to each webservice end point and have a queue listener dedicated to the message queue. If the message could not be delivered successfully, it could be put back on the queue for later delivery.have message queue